# Convergence of $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^q Log[n]^p}$ when $q$ is smaller than $1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

So for

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^q \log(n)^p}$$

If $q$ is greater or equal to $1$, the case is okay, I can perform comparison test or integral test respectively.

But what if $q$ is smaller than $1$? What method can I use?

Answer (score 1):

For $q<1$, recall the elementary fact that for any $\delta>0$ and $N$ sufficiently large, one has $n^\delta>\log^p(n)$ for all $n>N$. In particular, take $0<\delta<1-q$. Now we have $$\frac{1}{n^q\log^p(n)}>\frac{1}{n^{q+\delta}}$$ for $n>N$. Observing $q+\delta<1$, we use a simple direct comparison with the series and conclude that the series diverges.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Cauchy condensation test :

> If $u_n=\frac{1}{n^x.log(n)^y}$, using Cauchy condensation test the series converges $\sum u_n$ if $x>1$, and the divergence for $x<1$ :

We have for $u_n=\frac{1}{n^x}$,  $$2^n.u_{2^n}=\frac{2^n}{2^{nx}}=2^{n.(1-x)}$$ then $\sum u_n$ converges if and only if $x>1$

> For the limit case we have $u_n=\frac{1}{n.log(n)^y}$,

In this case,

$$2^n.u_{2^n}=\frac{1}{n.ln(2)^y}$$ wich converges if and only if $y>1$.

If you want only the case $x<1$, we have $nu_n=\frac{1-x}{\log(n)^y}\rightarrow +\infty$ when $n$ tends to $+\infty$ because $1-x>0$

Comment: convergence when y > 1? but that can be compared with 1/n, and hence diverges everywhere?

Comment: @user1819047 I am not sure I fully understand. But the case $y>1$ cannot be compared with $1/n$. I think you mean $x<1$ and yes using the limit with $\varepsilon$ you can compare with the harmonic series.